# How to disable pop-out option in pdf viewer with google doc from Webview in React Native

Tags: react-native, pdf, ecmascript-6, webview, google-signin

I am displaying PDF file in Webview which is getting as URL from server. To display that, I have used google drive viewer like following.

```
let uri = pdfURL;

      if (/\.pdf$/.test(uri)) {
        uri = `https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=${uri}`;
      }

            <WebView
              source={{ uri }}
              style={styles.webView}
              onLoad={() => this.hideSpinner()}
              startInLoadingState
              scalesPageToFit
              embedded
              onError={(err) => {
              }}
            />
```

But, It is displaying share option, Once tap on it, It is showing Google SignIn, I want to disable SignIn option.

Any suggestions?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why are you using google drive?

Comment: @Idan Thanks for your response, You mean, Do I need to use library to show pdf?

Comment: can't you use the shareable link from that file in google drive ?

Comment: No, I have to disable googlesignin

Comment: Could you share your pdf URL?

Comment: Sorry, I can't share due to privacy, But, For  your reference, You can check following sample http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I have not find any solution for this issue, But, I integrated following library to display pdf from URL and then my issue resolved. Hoping this will helps someone in future.

**react-native-pdf**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pdf